# Load element from page, after page has loaded completely

Tags: jquery

I have a page (/mysite/page1)

This page loads other pages into itself using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div id="header_container"></div>
<div id="table_container"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#header_container").load("/mysite/header")
        $("#table_container").load("/mysite/table")
        }
    )
```

Now, I want to have a second page (/mysite/page2) that uses only the contents of #table_container on page1.

In page2, when I try:

```
<div id="other_table_container"></div>
```

and:

```
$("#other_table_container").load("/mysite/page1 #table_container")
```

The result is empty, I think because page1 says "I'm loaded" before the #table_container is loaded with /mysite/table.

How can I make sure that all the jQuery requests on page1 are loaded before loading them into page2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of solving this problem is to use a parent callback in a child iFrame .

Consider having page 1 in a hidden iframe on page 2.

```
<iframe src="/mysite/page1" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

In the source of page 2

```
function loadPage1()
{
    $("#other_table_container").html($("iframe").contents());
}
```

And then in the source of page 1

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#header_container").load("/mysite/header", function(){
            $("#table_container").load("/mysite/table", function(){
                parent.loadPage1();
            ));
        });
    }
));
```

If you wanted to get a specific id from the page 1, like `#table_container`, you could simply change the method `loadPage1()` to accept a variable, `loadPage1(html)`:

```
function loadPage1(html)
{
    $("#other_table_container").html(html);
}
```

And then in your page 1 source:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#header_container").load("/mysite/header", function(){
            $("#table_container").load("/mysite/table", function(){
                parent.loadPage1($("#table_container").html());
            ));
        });
    }
));
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution. What additional steps would I need to take to POST data to the iframe's src?

Comment: You could use a good ol' fashioned $.post statement and send the callback HTML to the .html() of the iframe (or it might be .load() for an iframe; not sure off the top of my head).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#header_container").load("/mysite/header");
    $("#table_container").load("/mysite/table", function() {
       // #other_table_container shouldn't be loaded until #table_container is loaded
       $("#other_table_container").load("/mysite/page1 #table_container")
    });
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/load/ under the Callback Function section.

Comment: In which page's JS should this be placed?

Comment: The page that is loading the other pages into its divs.

Comment: +1 Something similar to this will work if page1 contains this code. However, this requires the child page (page1) to be aware of the parent (page2). While this will work fine in this simple application, this practice is not very easily extendable. Thanks for the reply.